# Spring Data Mongo MapReduce javascript not being escaped

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to  run mapReduce using Spring Data Mongo as per the documentation

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/

I have run into trouble loading the javascript files. When I include my map.js and reduce.js files the newlines are there for example \n\r\t etc. I used this online tool http://jscompress.com/ to compress the file into one line. The Files are then loaded but I get an error:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Command execution failed:  Error [ns doesn't exist],

Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "ns doesn't exist"}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.handleCommandError(MongoTemplate.java:1814)
    ... 32 more

I have tried loading the files as strings and escaping the javascript. The same javascript works well using the mongo driver ie.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("product_data");
DBCollection catalogData = db.getCollection("catalogData");
MapReduceCommand cmd = new MapReduceCommand(catalogData, stringMap, stringReduce, "map_reduce_java_test", MapReduceCommand.OutputType.REPLACE, null); 
catalogData.mapReduce(cmd);
```

and this does not work:

```
mongoOperations.mapReduce("catalogData", stringMap, stringReduce, new MapReduceOptions().outputCollection("map_reduce_java_test")
        .finalizeFunction(stringFinalize).outputTypeReplace(),
    CatalogItem.class);
```

any help or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look at this. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce your problem.
Which Version of Spring Data MongoDB are you using?
You are refering to a rather old version of Spring Data MongoDB the current version is 1.4.1:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongo.mapreduce

The M/R code for the pure MongoDriver and Spring Data MongoDb doesn't seem to match, e.g. you are not using the finalizeFunction.
Would you mind writing a test case that reproduces the issue?

You can use the MapReduceTests for that:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapreduce/MapReduceTests.java#L58

This is what I tried:

```
@Test
public void shoudSupportRunningCompressedJavaScriptAsMapReduceCommands() {

    createMapReduceData();

    MapReduceResults<ValueObject> results = mongoTemplate.mapReduce(
            "jmr1",
            mapFunction,
            reduceFunction,
            new MapReduceOptions().outputCollection("map_reduce_java_test").outputTypeReplace()
                    .finalizeFunction("function(key,reducedValue){return reducedValue}"), ValueObject.class);

    assertThat(results, is(notNullValue()));

    Map<String, Float> m = copyToMap(results);

    assertEquals(1, m.get("a").intValue());
    assertEquals(2, m.get("b").intValue());
    assertEquals(2, m.get("c").intValue());
    assertEquals(1, m.get("d").intValue());
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. I got this to work, the ns exception means the namespace was not found. It was still necessary to  compress the javascript files but after that loading them using classpath:FILENAME worked. I think the collection name from the @Document field was not matching with the collection names given as parameter to MapReduce